# How to export a lwjgl3 application

Tags: java, lwjgl

> How to export a lwjgl3 application.

Im currently creating a LWJGL3 application. Previously when i was using LWJGL2 i used a .jar program called [JarSplice](http://ninjacave.com/jarsplice)
 and it worked fine: you would add your application jar, libraries and there natives but now when i try it with LWJGL3 it gives me all sorts of error and i do not know how to get rid of them.

If you know how i could export such an application, please let me know.

Thanx in advance.

Comment: show your error please?

Comment: @QingfeiYuan [This](https://imgur.com/ERZNTKA) is a screenshot of one of the errors i get. If i remove the .jar that provides this error i get a different error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [launch4j](http://launch4j.sourceforge.net) to export jar files to .exe or other formats you can also add libraries and change all sorts of variables.